# How to override hash and isEqual for NSManagedObjects?

Tags: ios, hash, nsmanagedobject, nsset

We have a bunch of NSManagedObjects of various types.
Some of them have members that are NSSet's of other NSManagedObjects.
The problem is that I really need to override the hash and isEquals methods of the objects that are IN the set - but they are NSManagedObjects.
I'm having problems with getting multiple identical objects in the set.
As far as I can tell, since hash defaults to the object address - all objects are different.  So I need to override hash and isEquals - but can't see any way to do it.

What we have is a bunch of stuff in the System, and more comes in via XML - sometimes repeats of the existing objects. When they are the same, I don't want dups added to the set.

Comment: You explicitly can not override isEqual or hash on NSManagedObject.

Comment: So, that means the NSSet's that are created can't really be treated as NSSets? bleh.

Comment: It depends how you're defining equality. If the objects are equal why do you have different instances for each?

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554138/unique-identifier-for-nsmanagedobject

Comment: I could have sworn I replied to this 2 days ago...
The other question refd by batkuip doesn't seem to be really relevant.
There are dups because I'm loading a big block of XML, and the server sometimes re-sends an object.  So I want to prevent the dups from being added.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above by Wain, [NSManagedObject documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObject/objectID) states that you must not override `hash` or `isEqual:`. So this means a stock `NSSet` does not do what you need.

Some of your options are:

- Enumerate the `NSSet` contents to identify and remove duplicates
- Write a factory method for your `NSManagedObjects` that will return the same object when given the same inputs
- Fix the XML to not include duplicated objects
- Unique the objects coming from the XML before they become `NSManagedObjects`
- Modify the input XML to include a unique identifier that you can track, assuming the duplicated objects are exact duplicates
- Implement your own NSSet-like collection class that performs a different uniquing test than `hash` and `isEqual:`